# How do I create a new task in Asana using Alfred?

Tags: asana, asana-api, asana-connect

I'd like to use Alfred (Mac app) to create a new task in my Asana account from anywhere on my computer (I'm not a programmer). I'm trying to create a workflow where the search query can be used to create a new task. Is there a way of using the "JSON Config" option in Alfred to add a new task to my account?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is an integration listed on our [apps page](https://asana.com/apps/alfred) for an Alfred integration. It was made by an outside developer, so I hope it works for you - I used to use Alfred until OS X added Spotlight Search, at which time I sadly drifted away, but I remember it was totally sweet! Hopefully you can get it up and going!

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me. Make sure you run the commands mentioned with your username.

http://www.andrewboni.com/2016/12/31/an-alfred-3-compatible-asana-workflow/

Comment: i used PERSONAL ACCESS TOKENS. This works like a charm